# Duplicated div lost style

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a div like this, intended to be a dynamic field creator.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child1'>
        <input type='text'></input>
    </div>
    <div id='child2'>
        <input type='text'></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/xj0c50th/, the styles in new cloned divs are lost.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Your style is actually being applied just fine. If you inspect the elements, you'll notice that the style is there and the widths are correctly applied.

The problem is that you are copying the elements, but not the whitespace. Since input and label are by default inline-block elements, the whitespace is relevant.

Comment: Supporting [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj0c50th/3/) :) (Ofcourse, I don't recommend inserting whitespaces like this but just for proof)

Answer (score 1):

the only thing you are missing is the spaces between elements.. check out this fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/xj0c50th/2/

i added styles to the elements and strung together the original elements.

CSS

```
label, input {
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
button {
    width: 25px;
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="tag1">Label</label><input id="tag1" type="text" style="width:100px;"><label for="path1">Path</label><input id="path1" type="text" style="width:350px;"><button id='btn1' onclick="addmore()"> + </button>
```